# select the rows affected by an update

Tags: sql, mysql

If I have a table with this fields:

```
int:id_account
int:session
string:password
```

Now for a login statement I run this sql UPDATE command:

```
UPDATE tbl_name
SET session = session + 1
WHERE id_account = 17 AND password = 'apple'
```

Then I check if a row was affected, and if one indeed was affected I know that the password was correct.

Next what I want to do is retrieve all the info of this affected row so I'll have the rest of the fields info.
I can use a simple SELECT statement but I'm sure I'm missing something here, there must be a neater way you gurus know, and going to tell me about (:
Besides it bothered me since the first login sql statement I ever written.

**Is there any performance-wise way to combine a SELECT into an UPDATE if the UPDATE did update a row?**
Or am I better leaving it simple with two statements? Atomicity isn't needed, so I might better stay away from table locks for example, no?

Comment: In Oracle you have SQL%Rowcount to check **how** **many** rows were affected by the last del/upd/ins. But to retrieve actual row, you have to `SELECT`. Try to google for analog in MySQL

Comment: I think I'd go for simplicity and just follow up with a query -- as atomicity isn't needed.

Comment: Don't worry: "session = session + 1" is atomic in itself. My feeling is you're better off with two statements.

Comment: @Poni - It seems like some design problem, why would you need to store password into session table? This session table, you just need session, and id_count. Perform something like `insert into tbl_name select id_account, 1 from YOUR_USER_TABLE where id_account=17 AND password='apple' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE session=session+1;`

Comment: @ajreal: The table you're looking at is a very simplified example and doesn't really represent my table, don't forget that (:

Comment: @Poni - Agree, but you should not **de-normalize** it. I assume you don't want to update password on multiple tables if user change the password.

Comment: @ajreal, `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is still an insert statement which will not return any records, which is what Poni wants... also it is better not to put answers in comments section (it makes it hard for people to vote)

Comment: @Unreason - noted. PS: **PUNDIT** badges (Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) (do read about details in the docs).

Following up by SQL is ok and simple (which is always good), but it might unnecessary stress the system.

Comment: I think you're confusing my question with another, or something. I can't see how this answer relates to the question, hehehe

Comment: @Poni, ah I see, was following up on Alexander's comment about oracle. As for the real question - no you can't do that in SQL, two queries are going to be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the same WHERE statement for SELECT. It will return the modified rows, because your UPDATE did not change any columns used for lookup:

```
UPDATE tbl_name
SET session = session + 1
WHERE id_account = 17 AND password = 'apple';

SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE id_account = 17 AND password = 'apple';
```

An advice: never store passwords as plain text! Use a hash function, like this:

```
MD5('apple')
```

Comment: Thanks Silver although I'm not sure this is what I'm going to do, as making the server compare the password twice is useless, that is what I'm sure about (: Oh and thanks for the advice!

Comment: For anyone browsing here after 2008, **do not** use MD5 as a hash function for passwords.  As of 2021, good hashing algorithms include PBKDF2, bcrypt, and Argon2, (all with salts).

Answer (score 0):

This won't work for statements such as...

```
Update Table
Set Value = 'Something Else'
Where Value is Null

Select Value From Table
Where Value is Null
```

You would have changed the value with the update and would be unable to recover the affected records unless you stored them beforehand.

```
Select * Into #TempTable 
From Table
Where Value is Null

Update Table
Set Value = 'Something Else'
Where Value is Null

Select Value, UniqueValue
From #TempTable TT
Join Table T
TT.UniqueValue = T.UniqueValue
```

If you're lucky, you may be able to join the temp table's records to a unique field within Table to verify the update.  This is just one small example of why it is important to enumerate records.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effected rows by just using @@RowCount..

```
select top (Select @@RowCount)  * from YourTable order by 1 desc
```